# Design of a money skew economy (target: museums/libraries loan rotation sharing)

Tags: mathematical-economics, money-supply, theory

I was thinking about libraries and museums, and began wondering how such institutions might institute what I would describe as a "money skew economy."  [Skew in the math sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines), of two lines that do not intersect, and are not parallel.

What I mean in "tell to me like I'm five" is trading blocks, where the rich kid can't just buy the blocks.

From a museum perspective, a $1B wealth individual cannot simply ask "what's your price?"

Specifically, the task of implementing art trades among institutions, which might allow a small town library to realistically try to get an original copy of the US Constitution [on loan rotation?] (without just obtaining a massive donation)

The best I thought of was something like a "kudos" or "thank you" economy with incentivized behavior for the "credits?"

Such as:  The Smithsonian has a lot of "high Ask objects" from a market perspective, that other museums / libraries would like to have a chance at displaying, even if only on a short rotation.

Little Library doesn't have much, other than some local objects.

Smithsonian can "provide" the credits to borrow big stuff, by doing collections based on local regions, with the local libraries loaning out what would otherwise not be "that" valuable.

If enough institutions (Library of Congress, the Met, MoMA, California Science Center, Houston Museum, ect...) participated, then there could be something like a Bid / Ask on loan rotations, with several big institutions doing local region shows.

However, many issues, which is where the "money skew" comes in.

- "Luring" high money objects to low security institutions for theft
- Wealthy buying rotation credits
- Small institutions start with less to begin with
- The market still just tends want the stuff that's "expensive"
- Small institutions have to deal with existing market realities (land, labor)

***Question:***

How to build a loan rotation economy that is "money skew" (like an economy, yet of a character to be like a line that does not cross, or parallel the existing money economy)